# Resources NotFoundException when inflating layout

Tags: android

`Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ActivityTablet}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f0b0023 at`

I found in crashlytics that I get pretty often this type of error.
I started to look after `0x7f0b0023` id in my project and it reference to layout called "R.layout.activity_test".

The only place where I interact with this layout in `ActivityTablet` is where I inflate view by using `setContentView(..)` where I pass view as `return R.layout.activity_test;`

The interesting thing is, that when I click `R.layout.activity_test` it shows two layouts:

1. R.layout.activity_test (layout-sw600dp)
2. R.layout.activity_test (layout-sw600dp-land)

Could the error get caused because of the confusion of these two layouts? How to fix this?

Comment: it's might not be because of layout but due to some id mismatch or some invalid text in your views too

Comment: @VivekMishra How to make sure exactly what's causing this, if this is the only information I get from crashlytics? I also use ButterKnife with BindView annotations.

Comment: AFAIK There are no sure shot ways to find this. You have to figure it out based on the complete stacktrace

Comment: And post your complete stacktrace

Comment: since you have very specific layout above and the device where you test incase does not found layout in that case your resource will never be found , hence it is recommended to add default layout.xml also.